# Maximize the Minimum

Tags: cvxpy

I've got a vector (which will by dynamic in length depending on the problem), which is determined by the function Ax - b, where A and b are determined and x is a variable. I would like to maximize the minimum value of the resulting vector Ax - b. The problem is that cvxpy.atoms.elementwise.minimum.minimum doesn't take vectors as inputs, but rather individual expression.

My current code is:

```
cvxpy.Problem(cvxpy.Maximize(cvxpy.atoms.elementwise.minimum.minimum(A*x - b)))
```

and the error is obviously:

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg2'
```

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this? Thank you for any help.

Comment: I think I found the answer with cvxpy.atoms.min, but would be interested if anyone had any other suggestions.

Comment: Please explain what "minimum value of the resulting vector" means.

Comment: I mean maximize lowest individual element in the vector.

Comment: Lowest in absolute value?